# c++11 lambda expressions

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Today I was doing some catch-up on c++11 (as we have not moved on yet). One of the reasons to switch as stated by a lot of people seems to be lambda expressions. I am still unsure on how they offer something new.

For instance using c++11:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto func = [] () { std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl; };

    func();
}
```

seems to be very similar to:

```
#include <iostream>

#define FUNC( )\
        do { std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl; } while(0)


int main()
{
    FUNC();
}
```

What would lambda expressions offer me that I can't currently already do?

Comment: You can't use your version in place where a comparator is required, for example. Also macros are C relict.

Comment: you're seriously comparing a lambda function with a macro?

Comment: No, I said that to me it looks like they give the same result and I was merely asking a question as to what the difference is. I don't quite understand why this needs to be downvoted or be compared to "trained dolphin attackers".

Comment: I didn't downvote. Your question is perfectly valid. Macros are trained dolphin attackers. They are the worst tool imaginable for *almost* any purpose. I'm not suggesting that *you* or the *question* are trained dolphin attackers.

Comment: @Lieuwe Well I didn't downvote, I was just puzzled by the question. Macros are evil. They are a text replacement tool only. No error checking possible whatsoever. lambdas are proper functions. The compiler actually understands them.

Comment: I never realised people where so against macros. I see them everywhere and I have used them on occasions. But thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Yeah - I think the downvotes are a little extreme - some people still haven't learned some of the C++ "things you could do but shouldn't"... downvoting them for not knowing is too much.

Comment: @Lieuwe I would be really concerned for my mental health if I started seeing macros everywhere. Either that, or you read a lot of bad code.

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade Downvoting for not knowing things that are in books is *not* too much. It shows that the asker didn't put any effort into learning the subject.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz To an extent. I'd reckon 90% of the solutions to problems found on this site can be found in some book somewhere. But I see your point - this kind of stuff can be found in the most simple beginner books.

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade and that's just an example of how lazy people really are.

Comment: @Bartek, I understand your point of view, but I _am_ seeing macros (albeit not everywhere) in production code ran on hundreds of computers and on servers for some of the UK's largest companies. And (from what I can see) there has never been a problem related to the use of macros with it (I am not justifying the use of macros here). I have never been taught how to write software by anyone and I suspect that there are a lot of people like myself. In this case I don't think I was "lazy" because I could have found this answer in some book somewhere - I just wanted to see some opinions here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293608.aspx sums up the main points and more on the subject in great detail. Here is the salient excerpt:

> A lambda combines the benefits of function pointers and function
>   objects and avoids their  disadvantages. Like a function objects, a
>   lambda is flexible and can maintain state, but  unlike a function
>   object, its compact syntax doesn't require a class definition.  By
>   using lambdas, you can write code that's less cumbersome and less
>   prone to errors than the code for an equivalent function object.

There are examples on the site showing more differences and comparisons.

Also...conventional wisdom is never use macros in C++:

http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/12/17/macros-why-theyre-evil/

Answer (score 1):

A less obvious benefit of lambdas when used with the standard algorithms is that the programmer is not required to think of a name for the lambda function, and [naming things is considered to be a difficult task in programming](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html).

Additionally, the code executed via the standard algorithms is often used to invoke a member function(s) on each object in the supplied range, with the name of the functor, or function, often just parroting the name of the member function being invoked and adding nothing to readability of the code. Contrived example:

```
struct object
{
    void execute() const {}
};

void run_execute(object const& o) { o.execute(); }

std::vector<object> v;

std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), run_execute);

std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](object const& o) { o.execute(); });
```

Admittedly this is a minor benefit but still pleasant.